# Electrostatic Potential, Potential Energy, Method of Images

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, potential-energy, conductors

I am a beginner in problem solving in the field of electrostatics. Well equipped with basic strategies and use of gauss' law. I wanted to analyze the situation below and couldn't wrap my head around (it's rather basic indeed).

A conducting sphere of radius ***R*** has a point charge q at a distance ***a*** from the center (***a<R***)

1. Is the charge distribution on the outer surface uniform
2. Can we find the charge distribution on the inner surface using method of images if the conductor is not grounded
3. Knowing this, can we find the potential energy of the system in this situation.

I think the most intriguing one is the 3rd one.

I read that the work done in bringing a point charge near grounded conductor from infinity is zero (I saw this proof in another stackexchange question)

> [How can the work done in bringing a charged particle from infinity to a grounded conductor be zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/279517/how-can-the-work-done-in-bringing-a-charged-particle-from-infinity-to-a-grounded)

Since here the conductor is not grounded, the net charge at any instant on the sphere is zero, and the charge induced on the outer surface (non uniform) also gives rise to equal and opposite ***uniform*** charge distribution on the inner surface so as to keep the electric field inside = 0

Hence can we say that the work done in bringing the charge near the surface corresponds to the work done in brining the charge near a spherical charge distribution (Work due to outer distribution is 0 and will only be done against the inner charge distribution which is uniform)

Comment: Jackson spends about half a chapter working out all these facts.

Comment: Thanks alot for letting me know, I will refer to the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your problem statement $a < R$, so the charge is inside the spherical conductor, but in your logic near the end, you seem to assume the charge is outside of the sphere. I will show how to use the method of images in both cases.

a < R:
If the charge q is at $(a,0,0)$ put an image charge of charge $q'=-Rq/a$ at $(R^2/a,0,0)$ , i.e. outside of the sphere. This will put the potential at the inner wall of the conductor (at radius R) to 0. The induced surface charge will equal $\frac{dV}{dn}|_{r=R}$. On the outer surface, a constant charge density will occur, so the total charge on the conductor is 0.

a>R:
The charge density on the inner wall of the conductor must vanish since otherwise there would an electric field in the conductor.
If the charge q is at $(a,0,0)$ put an image charge of charge $q'=-Rq/a$ at $(R^2/a,0,0)$, and also a charge $q''$ at the origin, where $q''$ must be determined.
These charges will put the potential at the outer wall of the conductor (also at $r=R$?) to $q''/R$. The charge density on the outer wall will be given by $\frac{dV}{dn}|_{r=R}$, and there will be a value of $q''$ so that the total charge on the outer wall vanishes.

If you want to determine the potential energy of this configuration, you could try to integrate the charge densities against the potential generated by all the other charges, but I don't know if this is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks alot, I got how to use the method of images,  how would the charge density vary then if the conductor is grounded

Comment: You want the V=0 solution. For a<R you already have this, for a>R it means choosing q''=0. You still calculate charge via dV/dn, which will now be shifted by a constant.

Comment: One more thing, is the image charge also the center of induced charge on the sphere?